# Apache tomcat <error-page> tag in conf/web.xml not rendering an error page

Tags: java, xml, apache, jsp, tomcat

In /conf/web.xml I've mentioned an  tag as follows:

```
 <error-page>
    <exception-type>401</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>403</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>404</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

before this I also mentioned just

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>404</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

but it's still rendering the same default page of tomcat instead of the custom "error.jsp" page. I'm stuck in the problem since last 13 hours.

Comment: Did you stop and restart Tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **error-code** instead of **exception-type**

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I've kept the page "error.jsp" inside the /conf directly and it is not getting rendered. Can you please tell me where should I keep my error.jsp so that it gets rendered when 404(page is not found)

Comment: is the url updating?

Comment: Now its working fine. Actually we have to place the error.jsp inside the ROOT directory of tomcat. Thanks for ur responses. I made a silly mistake of using <exception-type> in place of <error-code>. Thanks